# highcharts polar view on canvas

Tags: canvas, highcharts

I need to show a large number of series' (2000+ possibly) on a polar chart at the same time but having serious trouble with load times. I was thinking canvas might be a better way to go but after looking at the Highcharts heatmap canvas example (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas) I'm still struggling to understand how to do this for a polar chart.

Any ideas on how to help with load times or how to go about doing this with canvas using highcharts? I've not tuned off mouseover or tooltips for the fiddle below but these wont be needed in the production version.

Each series can have a slightly different number of data points which is why I have to explicitly set the angle.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73jyxc57/

```
$(function () {

    var linedata = [[0,93],[5,93],[10,99],[15,105],[20,111],[25,117],[30,123],[35,129],[40,135],[45,141],[50,147],[55,153],[60,159],[65,165],[70,171],[75,176],[80,182],[85,188],[90,194],[95,200],[100,194],[105,188],[110,182],[115,176],[120,171],[125,165],[130,159],[135,153],[140,147],[145,141],[150,135],[155,129],[160,123],[165,117],[170,111],[175,105],[180,99],[185,93],[190,93],[195,99],[200,105],[205,112],[210,118],[215,124],[220,131],[225,137],[230,143],[235,150],[240,156],[245,162],[250,169],[255,175],[260,181],[265,188],[270,194],[275,200],[280,194],[285,188],[290,181],[295,175],[300,169],[305,162],[310,156],[315,150],[320,143],[325,137],[330,131],[335,124],[340,118],[345,112],[350,105],[355,99]];

    var seriesData = [];

    // build the data
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 
        seriesData.push ({
            "data": linedata
        });
    }

    // Create a timer
    var start = +new Date();

    $('#polarChart').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    if (!window.isComparing) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {
                            text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
            },
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: seriesData
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: HighchartsJS uses SVG to render their charts so re-rendering that to html canvas would take longer--not shorter. Have you looked at ChartJS which has a native canvas polar chart: http://www.chartjs.org/ ...And about load times...What data format are you transmitting: JSON, XML, Binary...?

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at chartjs. In an example Highcharts themselves extend their library for rendering extremely large numbers of shapes (shapes not datapoints) to be canvas rather than svg for performance gains however (first fiddle in my post). Just no example for polar charts. Thanks

Comment: Oh and it's json I ajax in, also an issue

Comment: Try to disable all animations like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/73jyxc57/1/)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian I'll give that a try